# Заполнение двумерного String массива информацией из файла

Tags: java

У меня есть текстовый файл, который лежит в директории проекта. В нем, разделенные точкой, лежат группы профессий. Например

> Программист:Веб-дизайнер:Системный администратор.Биолог:Фармацевт:Учитель химии.

Моя задача заполнить String массив группами этих профессий. Точки - разделители элементов массива. В моем примере был бы массив из двух элементов.

В моем файле 100 таких групп. Мне требуется добавить в массив размером [10][10] все эти группы так, чтобы после каждого элемента кратного 10 цикл переходил, соответственно, к следующей строке.

Мой код (нерабочий)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String[][] array = new String[10][10];

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Alexey\\eclipse-workspace\\Plugin\\src\\MatProList.txt"))) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
                while ((char)br.read() != '.') {
                    array[i][c] = array[i][c] + (char)br.read();
                }
            }


            if (br.read() == -1) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти мою ошибку.

Comment: к следующей строке в файле или к следующему массиву?

Comment: Я имел ввиду, чтобы индекс [1][1] менялся на индекс [2][1]. То есть при прочтении каждой десятой группы профессий из файла у меня первый индекс массива изменялся.

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем случае, я бы считал все из файла и сделал бы через массивы:

```
      import java.util.Arrays;

      public class ArrayApp {
          public static void main(String[] args) {
              //Подготовка тестовых данных
              StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
              for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                  stringBuilder.append(i);
                  if (i % 10 == 0) {
                      stringBuilder.append(".");
                  } else {
                      stringBuilder.append(":");
                  }
              }

              //Здесь должно происходить получение всех данных из файла
              String result = stringBuilder.toString();
              System.out.println(result);
              //Начало обработки и формирование массива
              String[] array = result.split("\\.");
              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
              int length = array.length;
              String[][] resultArray = new String[10][10];
              for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                  String[] valArray = array[i].split(":");
                  int lengthC = valArray.length;
                  for (int c = 0; c < lengthC; c++) {
                      resultArray[i][c] = valArray[c];
                  }
              }
              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultArray));
          }
      }
```

Что касается Вашего кода, я бы в цикле while читал данные и сохранял в StringBuilder пока не встретил точку, затем обработал бы строку. Для этого завел бы внешнюю переменную счетчик для подсчета 10.

Comment: Я немного по-другому решил проблему - без считывания файла, но мой подход нерационален, поэтому сейчас осваиваю БД. В любом случае - спасибо. Думаю, Ваш ответ наиболее полно отражает решение поставленной мною задачи.